# Stop counter increment when it reaches 95

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want the counter to stop when it reaches 95 and play a sound for the user to know the limit has reached. I want to stop counting when the limit is reached. How do I implement this. Thanks in advance.**

```
 class NinetyFiveTabs extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      _NinetyFiveTabsState createState() => _NinetyFiveTabsState();
    }
    
    class _NinetyFiveTabsState extends State<NinetyFiveTabs> {
      int _counter = 0;
    
      void _incrementCounter() {
    
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
          }
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _incrementCounter,
            child: Scaffold(
    
    
              body: ListView(
    
                children: <Widget>[
    
                  Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 150.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
             
              
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this language, but in your _increment counter i think you should add an if statement like so:

```
void _incrementCounter() {
if(_counter < 95) {
    setState(() {
          _counter++;
          }
        );
}
else {alert-user-with-whatever-you-want-to}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check in your _incrementCounter function. Increment you're under 95, otherwise play the sound.

For playing sound you could use something like [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

```
 void _incrementCounter() {
    if (_counter < 95) {
       setState(() {
        _counter++;
      });    
    } else {
      _player.play('sounds/beep.mp3');
    }
  }
```

And then disable your button maybe?
You could do that with the onTap in the GestureDetector:

```
 onTap: _counter < 95 ? _incrementCounter : null;
```

or fire some other function after 95 is reached:

```
 onTap: _counter < 95 ? _incrementCounter : _someotherFunction;
```